# finding matches in 2D table

Tags: c++, algorithm, match, eigen

Say I have an Eigen::MatrixXf (4,5), with no duplicates, as follows :

```
    a      b    c     d     e
A: 0.60  0.70  0.80  0.90  0.00
B: 0.51  0.61  0.71  0.81  0.91
C: 0.41  0.31  0.21  0.11  0.01
D: 0.10  0.20  0.30  0.40  0.50
```

I need to find the matches between row(i) and column(j) with the value(i,j) being the smaller (minimum of minimum) one, with (i) or (j) picked only once.

**result of my method :**

My work led me to an (trivial) iterative approach starting from the top left to bottom right and searching for minimal matches, so far, i got the couples `(A,e =0.00) (B,a =0.51) (C,e =0.01) (D,a =0.10)`.

```
    a      b    c     d     e
A: 0.60  0.70  0.80  0.90  0.00
                             ^
B: 0.51  0.61  0.71  0.81  0.91
     ^
C: 0.41  0.31  0.21  0.11  0.01
                             ^
D: 0.10  0.20  0.30  0.40  0.50
     ^
```

**Wanted results**

So, As you can see, i got 'e' and 'a' picked twice as matches which is undesirable. My perfect matches would be instead `(A,e =0.00) ( D,a =0.10) (C,d =0.11) (B,b =0.61)` with leaving 'c' unmatched.

```
    a      b    c     d     e
A: 0.60  0.70  0.80  0.90  0.00
                             ^
B: 0.51  0.61  0.71  0.81  0.91
           ^
C: 0.41  0.31  0.21  0.11  0.01
                       ^
D: 0.10  0.20  0.30  0.40  0.50
     ^
```

There must be a way to do it but I couldn't figure it out !

here's my code :

```
for (i = 0; i < Score.rows(); i++)
{
    Correspondance correspondence;
    correspondence.source = source[i];
    int idx = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Score.cols(); j++)
    {
        if (Score(i, j) < Score(i, idx)) idx = j;
    }
    correspondence.target = target[idx];
    correspondences_.push_back(correspondence);
}

 with Source [A, B, C, D] and target [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Comment: But, you didn't get `a` and `e` twice for the _same_ row! Which is a valid output no? Anyway Can we see your logic? code

Comment: Is your code even working as intended? Swap `(A,e)` with `(C,e)` and `(A,d)` with `(C,d)` (you'd currently get `(A,e =0.01) (B,a =0.51) (C,e =0.00) (D,a =0.10)`). Would your perfect match still be `(A,e =0.01) ( D,a =0.10) (C,d =0.90) (B,b =0.61)` or would it instead be `(A,d =0.11) ( D,a =0.10) (C,e =0.00) (B,b =0.61)`? For the second solution, a greedy approach wouldn't be optimal. Are you trying to minimise the sum of the resulting values or something else?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I'd assume so, I think he wants the smallest elements with unique x and y values

Comment: you can always make "any" algorithm run faster by using more memory

Comment: @BeyelerStudios exactly, I need them unique. actually it's intended to target tracking.

Comment: In a copy of the original matrix, assign values as 999 after you pick one. So it won't be picked again?

Comment: @FirstStep it won't work with my code because for example `'B' will pick 'a' first` instead of  `D` or even `C`.

Comment: I don't get it yet.. `A` will pick `e` (because it is the smallest), `B` will choose any but `e`, `C` will choose any but `e` and whatever `B` chose.. etc right?

Comment: i edited my question. So, my goal is more like sorting the table contents and matching pairs with the sorted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda took this as a challenge and wrote up what I'd probably do to solve your problem. (Uses C++11 features)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

double data[4][5] = { 
    { 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 0.00 },
    { 0.51, 0.61, 0.71, 0.81, 0.91 },
    { 0.41, 0.31, 0.21, 0.11, 0.01 },
    { 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50 } };

struct Element
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double value;
};

std::vector<Element> find(double (&matrix)[4][5])
{
    std::vector<Element> elements;
    std::vector<Element> matches;

    // build vector of all elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            elements.push_back({i, j, matrix[i][j]});

    // sort all elements from smallest to largest
    std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 
    [](const Element& a, const Element& b)
    {
       return a.value < b.value;
    });

    while (!elements.empty())
    {
        // pull out smallest value
        Element smallest = elements[0];
        matches.push_back(smallest);

        // remove all other elements in the same row or column
        elements.erase(std::remove_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 
        [smallest](const Element& e)
        {
            return e.x == smallest.x || e.y == smallest.y;
        }), elements.end());
    }

    return matches;
}

int main()
{
    auto matches = find(data);

    // print values
    for (auto match : matches)
        std::cout << "("   << match.x 
                  << ","   << match.y 
                  << " = " << match.value 
                  << ")"   << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought about, but it's weird how can such a first sight trivial become this mind banging... Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understand:
You're searching for unique minimum values in each row. And you want to find the min values in order (smallest to largest).

That means you can't search row by row like you're doing now. You need to search the ENTIRE table 4 times to find the min value for each row. And after you find something successfully, get rid of the row and column that you found so that it doesn't get searched again.

I included 2 ideas for getting rid of rows/columns that are already found. They are labeled OPTION 1 and OPTION 2 in the code below. ;)

```
//search for 4 values
for (i = 0; i < Score.rows(); i++)
{
    //search ALL rows
    for (i = 0; i < Score.rows(); i++)
    {
        Correspondance correspondence;
        correspondence.source = source[i];
        int idx = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < Score.cols(); j++)
        {
            //OPTION 1: Do something here to reject indexes from row/col that are already "found"
            if (Score(i, j) < Score(i, idx)) idx = j;
        }       
    }
    //only record the answer after all rows are searched
    //this is the global minimum value
    correspondence.target = target[idx];
    correspondences_.push_back(correspondence);
    //OPTION 2: Do something here to eliminate the row/cols that are already "found" so that they don't get searched again
}
```

P.S. I don't know what a correspondence is in C++, so I treated it like an array problem where push/pop is an option